# How to Reorganize a pdf file into paragraph?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, ranking

I'm working on a project of captioning and for my data set I have to extract images and their caption from pdfs file.

I use pdftotext to extract the text from the pdfs but now I have to regorganize those text file into paragraphs conformly to the pdfs.

I'm using this code but I'm not satisfied because the strcuture of the output text is not exactly what I want.

```
import re
import os
from os import listdir

text_directory = 'Texte'

for name in listdir(text_directory):
    filename = text_directory + '/' + name
    #open the text file
    with open(filename,encoding="utf8") as file:
        data = file.read()
        # Split text by 2 line break to have a kind of bloc
        paragraphs = [item for item in data.split('\n\n') if item]
        rawParagraphs = []
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            newParagraph = []
            # Split the bloc by line break 
            lines = paragraph.split('\n')
            for line in lines: 
                # Split lines by 2 white spaces to have kind of colones
                cols = [item for item in line.split('  ') if item]
                newParagraph.append(cols)
            # Find max cols of pg
            maxcol = max([len(line) for line in newParagraph])
            # Patch lines
            for index, line in enumerate(newParagraph):
                if len(line)< maxcol:
                    if lines[index].startswith(' '):
                        for i in range(maxcol-len(line)):
                            line.insert(0, '')
                    else:
                        for i in range(maxcol-len(line)):
                            line.append('')
                newParagraph[index]= line
            rawParagraph = []
            # Join line to have paragraph per colones
            for i in range(maxcol):
                for j in range(len(newParagraph)):
                    rawParagraph.append(newParagraph[j][i])
            rawParagraph = ' '.join(rawParagraph).replace('- ','')
            rawParagraphs.append(rawParagraph)
            # Create a text file to write the new paragraph
            textcle = open("Text_org" + "/" + name ,"w",encoding="utf8")
            # Get new paragraph
            references = [paragraph for paragraph in rawParagraphs if paragraph]
            # Write the paragraph in the texte file
            for index, reference in enumerate(references):
                text = f"{index} {reference}\n\n"
                textcle.write(text)
            textcle.close
```

Can someone help me perfected it ? Or is there another way to easly to do it ?

Comment: A typical PDF does not contain any information at all about paragraphs – or even separate lines. There is no "easy way" – the PDF format just is not designed with this is mind. Generally speaking, take what you get and be happy with it.

Comment: You say *"the strcuture of the output text is not exactly what I want"* but you don't explain what you want. But most likely @usr2564301 is right, in general there is very little information concerning text structure in a pdf.